# Is there a minimap plugin(function) in QGIS?

Tags: qgis

I'd like to add minimap(or mini-map) feature to my app, which were developed based on QGIS. I know there is a overview feature, however, it is quite different from minimap. The minimap should show basic features of canvas window, such as map, item.
It should be like this:
[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Overview will show any layers you add to it. What is it you're looking for in a minimap plugin that built-in overview does not provide?

[image]

Comment: Yes, overview has the minimap function. my *.qgs project contains serveral layers, each has scaled dependent visibility,  I tried `show in overview` before and nothing happened, I just thought there was no minimap function.

Answer (score 3):

In addition to the brilliant suggestion by @Jakob, there is the **Auxiliary Window** plugin which opens up a new window showing some basic map features such as showing/hiding layers, adding/removing layers from the main window etc:

[image: Auxiliary Window]

Similarly to the *Dockable MirrorMap* plugin, the **Auxiliary Window** also allows for multiple windows to be loaded.

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 2):

There is a plugin called 'Dockable MirrorMap' that will give you an extra map, where you can control layers shown.

Comment: It helps, but mirromap only displays what canvas window displays. It can't control the display of canvas. It would be perfect if someone merges the 'Dockable MirrorMap' and 'overview' in one.